# Can I get married in the UK on a Marriage visitor visa then return home and apply for a Spouse visa?

Tags: visas, uk, weddings

Me and my partner intend to get married soon. I am from a non-EU country and my partner is a British citizen. Unfortunately we don’t meet the fiancee visa requirements yet, but will meet the financial requirements in half a year approximately.

Is it possible to get married in the UK on Marriage visitor visa, then come back home and apply for the spouse visa, as by that time we will meet the financial requirements?
The problem is, that we don’t want to wait separately all that time.

So, will I be eligible to apply for a spouse family visa from another country after holding a marriage visitor visa?

Answer (score 7):

To summarise the comments, no this will not be a problem and is the way to do this. The marriage visitor visa is used to come into the UK, get married and then leave again at the end of the visa, so as long as you comply with the rules it will have no negative impact on a future visa application.